# Receiving double image with bitmap on C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, outputstream

I'm trying to use the SDK of a sensor for intraoral x-ray. I managed to save the image, but the image doubled.

This is the function to save the image.

```cs
private void SaveImage(short[] data, int widht, int height)
{
    Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(widht, height);
    
    Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
    BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);
    
    IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);
    
    pic.UnlockBits(picData);

    pic.Save(@"C:\Users\WIM\Desktop\teste\teste\teste.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

[And this is the image saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reyYR.jpg)

I'm not used to coding in C#. So I'm not sure if I do this right, and if the problem is on the function where i save the image or on the way as populated short array (short[] data);

*[Update]*

As suggested, I added PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale. and the function was like this:

```cs
private void SaveImage(short[] data, int widht, int height)
{
    Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(widht, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
    
    Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
    BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat) ;
    
    IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);
    
    pic.UnlockBits(picData);

    pic.Save(@"C:\Users\WIM\Desktop\teste\teste\teste.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

And I got this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'GDI+ generic error.'
```

In this line:

```
pic.Save(@"C:\Users\WIM\Desktop\teste\teste\teste.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

*[Update]*

I tried to modify the pixel format, and I tested all the other 16bpp. This is the result:

[Format16bpp565](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgU5b.jpg)

[Format16bpp555](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV2Bn.jpg)

And for Format16bppArgb1555 result a transparent image.

Comment: How do you get the value for the `data` parameter? Without knowing what it contains could be a little tricky. Your SDK should have information on this.

Comment: Clearly, the pixel format is wrong. The `short[]` makes me imagine it's an array of 16-bit colour pixels, which means you should use a 16 bit per pixel image format, too. You didn't give a pixel format, which makes it default to 32bppARGB. Meaning each of your pixels on the final image is using two pixels of your data, resulting in wrong colours, two lines per line, and a half-filled image.

Comment: The original image is 16 bits grayscale. Try to lock as Format16bppGrayScale.

Comment: Have you tried to save the raw data to a file and examine it's content? Maybe you get this way a hint.

Comment: You mean to a txt file?

Comment: A bmp would be probably better.

Comment: Even png would work. Don't use jpeg for showing things like this; it's lossy, it blurs things, and it makes it impossible for anyone to analyse the data inside. Note, `System.Drawing` has no real support for 16bpp greyscale, so If it's that, you need to treat it as 8bpp, only use the higher of the 2 bytes, and generate a gray colour palette for it.

Answer (score 0):

The pixel format `Format16bppGrayScale` exists in `System.Drawing`, but it is not actually implemented or supported. That's why it gives an error when trying to save it.

If this is indeed 16 bpp greyscale data, the only way to solve this in `System.Drawing` namespace is to reduce your data from 16-bit to 8-bit, treat it as an indexed (paletted) image, and just give it a grey fade from [0,0,0] to [255,255,255] as colour palette.

```
public static void SaveImage(short[] data, int width, int height, string path)
{
    int dataLen = data.Length;
    // This might not equal the width.
    int inputStride = dataLen / height;
    byte[] sourceData = new byte[dataLen];
    // Reduce Int16 to bytes by downshifting the data by 8 bits.
    // Effectively this divides the number by 256.
    for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; ++i)
        sourceData[i] = (Byte) (data[i] >> 8);
    // Make an 8bpp image
    using (Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed))
    {
        BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pic.PixelFormat);
        // Get actual stride from BitmapData
        Int32 targetStride = picData.Stride;
        Int64 scan0 = picData.Scan0.ToInt64();
        // Stride is ALWAYS rounded up to the next multiple of 4, so copy line by line to avoid issues.
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            Marshal.Copy(sourceData, y * inputStride, new IntPtr(scan0 + y * targetStride), width);
        pic.UnlockBits(picData);
        // Requesting Bitmap.Palette makes a COPY, so get it out, edit it, and then reassign it.
        ColorPalette pal = pic.Palette;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
        pic.Palette = pal;
        pic.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```